# Why is there a diffence between the duration of video by ffmpeg and cv2.VideoCapture()?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

To get the duration of a video, I've tried the following two ways:

1. Using `cv2.VideoCapture(xxx.mp4)`, get its fps and total frames, and I got 30 and 5144. Which means its duration is `00:02:51.46`.
2. Using ffmpeg.ffprobe, it says:

   > `Duration: 00:02:51.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2542 kb/s
   >   Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180, 2404 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)`

---

What's the reason for this difference, which is more accurate?

Comment: ffprobe. Check the frame count using `ffmpeg -i in -c copy -f null -`

Comment: Did you compute the duration as follow: `num_frames / fps`.